# Spring-Security : Optimizing get currently authenticated user…

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am using Spring-Security for authentication. Due to excessive usage of getting the currently authenticated user mechanism, Profiler shows it as an 'Allocation Hotspot' and nearly 9.5kb memory is consumed for a single user. Is there any way to optimize this infrastructure.

PersonServiceImpl :

```
 @Override
    public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return personDAO.findPersonByUsername(authentication.getName());
        }
    }
```

If I somehow always can push the user in some cache from where it is retrieved after first retrieving, atleast that should improve the performance, but I have no idea how to do that. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [Spring Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) can help you here. Spring Cache first checks if a value for a certain method and key (which can be customized) is available and if so, will return the cache hit without entering the method at all. On a miss, it will execute the method and put the return value into the cache. The challenge is to provide a key which is unique to the users session.

Comment: @RomanVottner Looks promising. I have just put the cacheable annotation now, but the parameter cacheNames is not available. I believe it is removed in newer versions. Should the annotation be enough?

Comment: You can declare the cacheNames via `@CacheConfig(cacheNames="yourName", keyGenerator="customKeyGenerator", ...)` at class level and just annotate each method which should use the cache with `@Cacheable`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some variants. But also you can try to ue only Spring:
1. Extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User and add into your UserEntity (Person)

```
public class User extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {
    private Person sysUser; 

  public User(Person sysUser) {
        super(sysUser.getLogin(), sysUser.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>());
        this.sysUser = sysUser;
    }

public Person getYourUser(){
return sysUser;
}

}
```

2. Implements UserDetailsService using your User Entity and extended org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User

   ```
   @Service(value = "userService")
   public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
   @Autowired
   SecurityDAO securityDAO;

   @Override
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       User user = null;
       try {
           Person su = securityDAO.getUserOnlyByLogin(login);
           if (su != null)
               user = new User(Person);

       } catch (Exception e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       }


       return user;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Configure your Spring (xml or Annotation):

> ```
>  <beans:bean id="userService" class="your.pack.UserService"/>
>     <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
>         <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService"/>
>     </authentication-manager>
> ```

4. use your method

   @Override

   ```
      public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() {
           Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

           if (authentication == null) {
               return null;
           } else {  User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
               return user.getYourUser();
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of this, I have the login code already working.

Comment: This code allow to use Spring context for keeping information about your user. But if you need to do every time a request to the database I can advise EHCache